# Gitlab CI for Android: Build failed: exit status 1

Tags: android, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have one runner working on OS X El Capitan for my iOS and Android apps. iOS one works fine. Android one is causing problems.

After CI triggered I see in gitlab:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.5.2 (76fdacd)
Using Shell executor...
Running on <machine>..
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '<path>'...
Checking out 5c742952 as dev_CI...
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

I run gitlab-ci-multi-runner in debug mode by: `gitlab-ci-multi-runner --debug run`

What I see on the servers terminal is:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=darwin revision=76fdacd version=1.5.2
Starting multi-runner from /Users/<user>/.gitlab-runner/config.toml ...  builds=0
Checking runtime mode                               GOOS=darwin uid=501
WARNING: Running in user-mode.                     
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                 
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                   

Configuration loaded                                builds=0
concurrent: 1
checkinterval: 0
user: ""
runners:
- name: <runner name>
  limit: 0
  outputlimit: 0
  runnercredentials:
    url: <ci_url>
    token: <token>
    tlscafile: ""
  runnersettings:
    executor: shell
    buildsdir: ""
    cachedir: ""
    environment: []
    shell: ""
    ssh:
      user: ""
      password: ""
      host: ""
      port: ""
      identityfile: ""
    docker:
      dockercredentials:
        host: ""
        certpath: ""
        tlsverify: false
      hostname: ""
      image: ""
      cpusetcpus: ""
      dns: []
      dnssearch: []
      privileged: false
      capadd: []
      capdrop: []
      securityopt: []
      devices: []
      disablecache: false
      volumes: []
      cachedir: ""
      extrahosts: []
      networkmode: ""
      links: []
      services: []
      waitforservicestimeout: 0
      allowedimages: []
      allowedservices: []
      pullpolicy: ""
    parallels:
      basename: ""
      templatename: ""
      disablesnapshots: false
    virtualbox:
      basename: ""
      basesnapshot: ""
      disablesnapshots: false
    cache:
      type: ""
      serveraddress: ""
      accesskey: ""
      secretkey: ""
      bucketname: ""
      bucketlocation: ""
      insecure: false
    machine: null
sentrydsn: null
modtime: {}
loaded: true
  builds=0
Waiting for stop signal                             builds=0
Starting worker                                     builds=0 worker=0
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Trying to load /Users/<user>/.gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab.<domain>.com.crt ... 
Dialing: tcp gitlab.<domain>.com:443 ...      
Checking for builds... received                     build=16510 repo_url=https://gitlab.<domain>.com/<project>.git runner=<short_token>
Failed to requeue the runner:                       builds=1 runner=<short_token>
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.5.2 (76fdacd)  build=16510 project=101 runner=<short_token>
Shell configuration: environment: []
dockercommand:
- sh
- -c
- "if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /usr/local/bin/bash --login\nelif [
  -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then\n\texec /usr/bin/bash --login\nelif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then\n\texec
  /bin/bash --login\nelif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /usr/local/bin/sh
  --login\nelif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then\n\texec /usr/bin/sh --login\nelif [ -x /bin/sh
  ]; then\n\texec /bin/sh --login\nelse\n\techo shell not found\n\texit 1\nfi\n\n"
command: bash
arguments:
- --login
passfile: false
extension: ""
  build=16510 project=101 runner=<short_token>
Using Shell executor...                             build=16510 project=101 runner=<short_token>
Waiting for signals...                              build=16510 project=101 runner=<short_token>
WARNING: Build failed: exit status 1                build=16510 project=101 runner=<short_token>
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=1
Submitting build to coordinator... ok               build=16510 runner=<short_token>
Checking for builds... nothing                      runner=<short_token>
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Checking for builds... nothing                      runner=<short_token>
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Checking for builds... nothing                      runner=<short_token>
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
```

I need a hint how to find out the reason for failing build?

I see no script was called from my .gitlab-ci.yml file. You can have a look at it as well:

```
compile:
  script:
    - echo 'compiling'
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
    - ./gradlew assembleDevelRelease --debug
```

I created new runner on my local mac and it works well for Android and iOS projects. I cannot find out the reason why it is failing on my server.

It throws error directly after cloning repo. I noticed that all source code is cloned properly, however no script from .gitlab-ci.yml is called.